# Creating an object in a loop

Tags: javascript

This is a weird idea but let me explain. I have this:

```
client({
    Action: 'UrlInfo',
    'UrlInfo.Shared.ResponseGroup': 'Rank',
    'UrlInfo.1.Url': 'lupomontero.com',
    'UrlInfo.2.Url': 'yahoo.com',
    'UrlInfo.3.Url': 'weibo.com',
    'UrlInfo.4.Url': 'github.com',
    'UrlInfo.5.Url': 'monono.org'
},
```

So currently it's hardcoded in. I want to create the UrlInfo "array". I hope this explains what I want to do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
    var data = {'UrlInfo$'+i + 1 + 'Url':websites[i]};
}
```

And this doesn't work. How would I make it to work?

Comment: You would first create an empty object data.  `var data = {}`, then inside your loop.   `data['UrlInfo$'+i + 1 + 'Url'] =websites[i]};`

Comment: um `data[\`UrlInfo.${i}.Url\`] = websites[i];` ?

Comment: It would probably be a lot more convenient (both here and inside your client() function) to just put the websites array directly into that object, instead of splitting its components up into sequentially-named object keys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the resulting object first, then assign each website in the for cycle.

Try it like this:

```js
const websites = [
  'lupomontero.com',
  'yahoo.com',
  'weibo.com',
  'github.com',
  'monono.org',
];
    
const ret = {};
    
for (let i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
  ret['UrlInfo.' + (i + 1) + '.Url'] = websites[i];
}
    
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using simple `for` loop:

```js
const websites=["lupomontero.com","yahoo.com","weibo.com","github.com","monono.org"];
const data = {};
for (let i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
  data['UrlInfo.' + (i + 1) + '.Url'] = websites[i] || '';
}
console.log(data)
```

Or, in one line using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const websites=["lupomontero.com","yahoo.com","weibo.com","github.com","monono.org"];
const data = websites.reduce((o, a, i) => ({ ...o, ['UrlInfo.' + (i + 1) + '.Url']: websites[i]}), {})
console.log(data)
```

Comment: That works thanks! One question. Why the `null` at the end?

Comment: Just a rare case scenario where the data might be coming from ajax call, so just handling that and converting to empty string to get data properly.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Will select in 4min

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 features, you should be able to use `reduce` to compose objects like this, assuming `websites` is an array:

```
const data = websites.reduce((accumulator, website, currentIndex) => {
  accumulator[`UrlInfo.${currentIndex + 1}.Url`] = website
  return accumulator
}, {})
```

- Array.prototype.reduce() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
- String template literals for subbing in `${currentIndex}` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals